# How to scale loop cut instead of scaling whole mesh?

Tags: mesh, edit-mode

I want to scale the difference between to loop cuts. It worked great on another mesh in another project by pressing <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd> to scale the loop cut, but this time it scales the whole mesh with focus on the cutted area (as seen below).

I thought about what is different between this and the other mesh, but I can't find one.

[image]

[image]

[image]

https://vimeo.com/498472202

Comment: Hello :). Just a blind guess, but perhaps you enabled proportional editing? Please add an image of your whole viewport.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. :) I added an image above. Thank you.

Comment: Hey :). I'm not sure what different result you're expecting from scaling the loops. Could you illustrate? :)

Comment: I want to do what he is doing in this Video (it is in German, but you can see what I mean). I did what he say: I pressed s and x, but it does not work as shown in the video, it does what you see in the second picture above https://youtu.be/Om7XfWeeiD4&t=500

Comment: Oh. It works just fine for me. S (to scale) and then Z to constrain along axis. But if the shortcuts don't work, you can always use Scale tool gizmo to choose the axis :).

Comment: That is weird.
Here is a video that shows what I mean. It does not work, even with the scale tool gizmo. https://vimeo.com/498472202

Comment: Hi @DominikMeyer please add any new information to the body of your question as an [edit] so that other users are able to read it without needing to view the comments.Thanks :)

Comment: Oh, sorry. I will do that in future. :) Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main problems.

1. You're using *Pivot > Individual origins*, change it to *Median*
2. You have *Proportional Editing* enabled, disable it

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. :)

Comment: No problem :). Good luck with your project.

Comment: Thank you very much :)